# How to install Parallels Workstation in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: parallels

Hello guys i have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit on my pc and i wish to install Parallels Workstation (Virtual machine). I Personally loved it cause i have used it on windows also.

Whats the methods to install Parallels workstation on ubuntu :( I have searched a lot but couldn't find much.

Please help guys :)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

open your terminal type this

```
wget http://download.parallels.com/workstation/v6/en_us/parallels/update1-hf2/parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run
```

then

```
chmod +x parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run
```

then   `sudo ./parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run`

Comment: After adding the 2nd command in terminal (chmod +x parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run
./parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run) I am getting this message in terminal "You must have root privileges to run installation"  :(

Comment: i have edited the answer

Comment: oh ty i added the whole (chmod +x parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run ./parallels-workstation-parallels-en_US-6.0.13976.769982.run) command in 1 lol Thanks will give u feedback soon :)

Comment: Alright :D thanks finally worked :) thank you soo much

Comment: +1 because the OP didn't accept and you obviously solved his problem.