# How to install Parallels Workstation in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, virtualization, parallels

Is there a way to install parallels workstation on lastest ubuntu 12.10?

Comment: Why would it not be possible? Did you already try something? Give us some more info please.

Comment: Check http://askubuntu.com/questions/197342/how-to-install-parallels-workstation-in-ubuntu-12-04
The answer there should apply to this version as well.

Answer (score 1):

Parallels is not available for an Ubuntu host. You can use VirtualBox, VMWare, or kvm instead to run a VM on an Ubuntu host.

Comment: Can you give me the command liness for installing kvm plz :)